# How does SQL server determine the data type of a column derived through an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, precision, numeric

I have a sql statement

```
> SELECT SUM(UNIT*ISNULL((CAST(RATIO AS DECIMAL(18,5))/100),1)) AS UNITS
> into x_table from some_table
```

Above UNIT is int,
In the x_table i can see that UNITS is DECIMAL(38,9). How did sql server arrive at that particular data type. 
Thanks!

Comment: [Data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) determine the data type. Highest wins.

Comment: Appears it arrived at the correct answer - did you explicitly want it to round in some form? or do you mean how did it choose (38,9) for the precision / scale?

Comment: [SUM Returns the summation of all expression values in the most precise expression data type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I can see that the result will be a decimal but how did it come decimal(38,9) ? Thanks!

Comment: Also of relevance: [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @Andrew. Yes i want to know how it came to decimal(38,9).

Comment: That's covered in the document I linked above.

Comment: Thank you! I will go through it.

Comment: Actually you need to go through all three links!

Comment: Everybody: please stop adding answers as comments! Comments are for *clarifying or improving the question*. Any or all of those three links, with a few key sentences quoted, would have made good answers, but right now nobody can vote on, improve, or accept them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- All operands must be converted to the [datatype with highest precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). In this case UNIT and the literal 100 will we converted to `DECIMAL(p, s)`.
- `CAST(RATIO AS DECIMAL(18,5))` is of course `DECIMAL(18,5)`
- `(CAST(RATIO AS DECIMAL(18,5))/100)` is `DECIMAL(22,9)` - this is following the rules for the result of division [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with `100` being treated as `DECIMAL(3,0)`
- `ISNULL((CAST(RATIO AS DECIMAL(18,5))/100),1)` is `DECIMAL(22,9)` as `ISNULL` always takes the datatype of its first parameter.
- `UNIT *ISNULL((CAST(RATIO AS DECIMAL(18,5))/100),1)` is `DECIMAL(33,9)` using the rules for multiplication from the above link and `UNIT` treated as `DECIMAL(10,0)`
- `SUM(UNIT *ISNULL((CAST(RATIO AS DECIMAL(18,5))/100),1))` is `DECIMAL(38,9)` as the resulting type from [`SUM`-ming a decimal always has 38 precision and the original scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1):

The links and comments above will explain **HOW**, but if you need a quick answer or confirmation use `sp_describe_first_result_set` or `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set()`

Notice I removed `INTO ...`

**Example**

```
Declare @tsql nvarchar(max) =  N'SELECT SUM(UNIT*ISNULL((CAST(RATIO AS DECIMAL(18,5))/100),1)) AS UNITS from some_table'

exec sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql 

--------
-- OR --
--------

select column_ordinal
      ,name
      ,system_type_name 
 From  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@tsql,null,null )
```